# Access template parameter from class object

Tags: c++, templates, class-template

I have a class template in myclass.hpp:

```
template<class T, class P>
class myclass
{
....
};
```

In my main.cc I create an object of the class:

```
myclass<int, double> mc;
otherfunc<myclass>(mc);
```

In some other header file header1.hpp:

```
template<class MyClass>
void otherfunc(MyClass const &mc)
{
/* Access through 'mc' the underlying template parameters T and P*/
}
```

How can I access the template parameter T and P in header1.hpp?

Comment: `otherfunc<myclass>(mc)` is invalid with given `otherfunc` declaration. you might use `otherfunc(mc)` (let deduction occurs) or `otherfunc<myclass<int, double>>(mc)`.

Answer (score 7):

> How can I access the template parameter T and P in header1.hpp?

Provide `public` type definitions in your class `myclass`:

```
template<class T, class P>
class myclass
{
public:
     typedef T T_type;
     typedef P P_type;
....
};
```

Thus you can access those types as

```
typename myclass::T_Type x;
typename myclass::P_Type y;
```

elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Example:

```
template<class T, class P>
void otherfunc(myclass<T, P> const &mc)
{}
```

Alternatively:

```
template<class T, class P>
class myclass
{
    using ParamT = T;
    using ParamP = P;
};

template<class MyClass>
void otherfunc(MyClass const &mc)
{
    using ParamT = typename MyClass::ParamT;
    using ParamP = typename MyClass::ParamP;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## #1

One way is to typedef within `myclass`.

```
template<class T, class P>
class myclass
{
public:
    typedef T typeT;
    typedef P typeP;
};
```

And refer to them like

```
template<class MyClass>
void otherfunc(MyClass const &mc)
{
    typename MyClass::typeT myMember;
}
```

## #2

Another way is to use `decltype`. You likely don't literally need to use the template parameters, but intend to use the same type as a member or return value of a `myclass` member. Thus, something like this:

```
template<class T, class P>
struct myclass
{
  T memberT;
  P memberP;
};

template<class MyClass>
void otherfunc(MyClass const &mc)
{
  using T = decltype(MyClass::memberT);
  using P = decltype(MyClass::memberP);
  T var1;
  P var2;
}
```